# Rvest scraping US DOS website returning 403 access forbidden

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I was scraping US Department of States press releases on regular basis, but it suddenly respond access forbidden, I try from different computers and from cloud platforms but the result was the same. Also, I'm not allow to access RSS feed for the site:[text](https://www.state.gov/rss-feed/press-releases/feed/)

below is my code:

```r
options(stringsAsFactors = F)         # no automatic data transformation
options("scipen" = 999, "digits" = 4) # suppress math annotation
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(readtext)
library(webdriver)
library(gsubfn)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
library(urltools)
library(crul)
############################********Department_of_State*****##################################

HEADERS <- list(
  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"
  
)


US_Gov=tibble(url="https://www.state.gov/press-releases/page/",page=1)
US_Gov=rbind(US_Gov, US_Gov[rep(1, 4), ])
US_Gov=US_Gov %>% mutate(page=row_number())
US_Gov$page=paste0(US_Gov$url,US_Gov$page,"/")

df=US_Gov$page


ttt=lapply(df,function(x){
  
  HttpClient$new(x, header=HEADERS)$get()
})



t4=lapply(ttt,function(x){
  read_html(x$parse())
})

links=lapply(t4,function(x){
  html_attr(html_nodes(x, "a"), "href")
  
})

class=lapply(t4,function(x){
  html_attr(html_nodes(x, "a"), "class")
  
})




US_Links=plyr::ldply(links, cbind)
US_Class=plyr::ldply(class, cbind)


US_Data=bind_cols(US_Links,US_Class)
```

Rvest 403 access denied

Comment: The website probably has code to deter automatic scraping. It's common for sites to enforce some kind of rate limiting step so you don't overload the server with requests. Their [robots.txt](https://www.state.gov/robots.txt) page indicates a crawl delay of 5 seconds so make sure you are not sending too many requests in that window.

Comment: Not working even when I try to read one URL the result is: status: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidde

Answer (score 0):

Once / if you get out of their blacklist, try to slow down. `httr2::req_throttle()` for example provides a convenient method to include throttling in *dplyr* pipelines and displays a progress bar in interactive session.

Also, just setting the `user-agent` in the header is probably not enough, I didn't bother to test all combinations, but skipping just few random header values resulted in 4xx error.

```r
library(httr2)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

press_releases <- paste0('page/',1:5,'/') %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(\(page){
    request(paste0("https://www.state.gov/press-releases/", page)) %>% 
    req_headers(
      authority = "www.state.gov",
      accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
      `accept-language` = "en-GB,en;q=0.9",
      `cache-control` = "max-age=0",
      `sec-fetch-dest` = "document",
      `sec-fetch-mode` = "navigate",
      `sec-fetch-site` = "none",
      `sec-fetch-user` = "?1",
      `upgrade-insecure-requests` = "1",
      `user-agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    ) %>% 
    # 5s dealy
    req_throttle(rate = 12 / 60) %>% 
    req_perform() %>% 
    resp_body_html()
  })

press_releases %>% 
  map(\(html_doc) html_doc %>% 
        html_elements("a.collection-result__link") %>% 
        html_text() %>% 
        trimws() %>% 
        tibble::enframe(name = "link_n")) %>% 
  list_rbind(names_to = "page")
```

Result for first 5 pages:

```r
#> # A tibble: 50 × 3
#>    page    link_n value                                                         
#>    <chr>    <int> <chr>                                                         
#>  1 page/1/      1 Taiwan as an Observer in the World Health Assembly            
#>  2 page/1/      2 Joint Statement on the 2nd U.S.-Netherlands Cyber Dialogue    
#>  3 page/1/      3 United States Sanctions Additional Sinaloa Cartel Network of …
#>  4 page/1/      4 Assistant Secretary of State for International Organization A…
#>  5 page/1/      5 Secretary Blinken to Deliver Remarks at the World Food Prize …
#>  6 page/1/      6 Secretary Blinken’s Call with Israeli Minister of Foreign Aff…
#>  7 page/1/      7 The Attack on AHA Centre Convoy                               
#>  8 page/1/      8 Deputy Secretary Sherman’s Call with European External Action…
#>  9 page/1/      9 Secretary Blinken’s Meeting with North Macedonia’s Prime Mini…
#> 10 page/1/     10 Secretary Antony J. Blinken and North Macedonia’s Prime Minis…
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
```

BTW, some US gov sites tend to have a geoblock for somewhat surprising regions, for example I have never been able to directly access Census Bureau data from my EU location (3-4 different locations / service providers).